# How to represent an array of objects inside of another object as PostgreSQL tables React useState

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to represent below mentioned code as a table in a PostgreSQL database. I wonder if I could somehow make two related tables. I need the elements in state.pool array to be in relation with state.id.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: "",
    number: 0,
    type: "CODE",
    flag: false,
    pool: [
      {
        elementId: uuidv4(),
        value: 0,
        type: "NEW"
      }, 
      {
        elementId: uuidv4(),
        value: 1,
        type: "OLD"
      }
    ]
  });
```

I'm able to set a simple 1 dimensional database with raw query or sequelize but I'm not sure how to include this array of objects. Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **json**/**jsonb** type for pool column.
Since pool field is array, you will need to use `json_array_elements`/`jsonb_array_elements pgsql` functions in your queries, but it wont be any simpler if you use 2 tables.

You can read more [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

Comment: thank you, i thought that json/jsonb array elements must be of one type. Your suggestion worked